# How to make TOC lines automatically indent in a Word 2007 document

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, table-of-contents

I have an automatic Table of Contents in a translated Word 2007 document:

> [image]

In the original Russian document the "second-level" headings are indented:

> [image]

I translated the document using the SDL Trados Studio, I changed nothing in the settings. What should I tweak in the translated (English-language) document to make the TOC look indented, just like in the Russian original document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update (in the English document) the styles TOC 1 through TOC 9 (or whatever the number of levels you actually use) to reflect the indentation that you want. See [this question in the Microsoft Community forums](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_other/word-2007-table-of-contents-indentation-problem/06dff81f-6813-4e3c-a071-7765b00c6541).